# How does PHP (mysqli or pdo) run MySQL commands?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When using mysqli or PDO in a PHP script what are the mechanics that take place for the sql query to run?

Does the mysqli module run `shell_exec()` with a mysql command? I'm sure there is something more here.

**Edit**

More specifically what I wanted to know was what is the process that PHP takes to actually make a MySQL call, what are the mechanics involved for PHP to have access to the database.

Comment: No, it connects directly to the MySQL driver, typically mysqlnd

Comment: think about it: if it was calling out to shell_exec, transactions would be impossible. mysql cleans up when a connection is closed, so php would exec, run `mysql` at the cli, do a query, then disconnect... boom, no more transaction, no more locks, no more server-side variables, etc...

Comment: there's always proc_open, of course, but then getting data to/from would be very difficult as well. mysql cli wouldn't know it's really talking to php, and would do all kinds of fancy formatting/conversion to get things into human readable form, which php would just have to undo.

Comment: Browse around https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/pdo_mysql and https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/mysqlnd if you're really concerned with the implentation details. (A complete summary is off-scope, and unwarranted for such a skimp question.)

Comment: @mario really appreciate that will definitely go through the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thing called [Mysql C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html).

Both PHP extensions are written by implementing low-level C functions from this API.

Comment: is there a way to intercept the api call between php and mysql

Answer (score 1):

It connects directly over a socket to the server. There is no way to have connection pooling if you're just doing `shell_exec()`, which you may have noticed is an option. Not only that, but running another executable for every single query is insanely slow. As the other answer has mentioned, PHP uses C-bindings for Mysql which do all the hard work reading/writing sockets.